# Npm : Error: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I dont understand why my module already exist in my package.json and showing in my console
any idea please ?

```
Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-util'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `npm install` in your project folder